# Can i have my output only show 1 if both echo's have the same value?

Tags: php, attributes

Okay so on my website i have a template that show's information about my woocommerce products. It will show the attributes in a table. Now i have some attributes that show in two attribute categories because i have the same names for those.

At the moment i am showing the attributes as:

```
<td style="width: auto;"><?php 
                $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
                <?php echo $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dc-ac'); ?>
                <text>-</text>
                <?php echo $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dcac'); ?>
                </a>
            </td>
```

Now if my attributes have the same value is there any way that it only shows 1 of them? I will later try to figure out why it sometimes will show in the first attribute and sometimes in the second or on some products show on both attributes but i thought this would maybe be an option.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Maybe try somehting like this : `<?php $first = $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dc-ac'); echo $first; ?>` and for the second row: `<?php $second = $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dcac'); if ($first != $second) {echo $second;} ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I should have write it as anwser and not in comment if it works, my bad ! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get attributes before, and then, compare them before to write :

```
<td style="width: auto;"><?php
    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
    $attr1 = $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dc-ac');
    $attr2 = $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dcac');
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo $attr1 ; ?>
    <?php if ($attr2 != $attr1) : ?>
        <text>-</text><?php echo $attr2; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```